# Що означає фразеологізм / словосполучення "грьобаний стид"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми, словосполучення, ненормативна-лексика

У статті ["Грьобаний стид" - рівнянка розповіла, як у новому потязі возять контрабанду](http://ogo.ua/articles/view/2017-08-27/88804.html) натрапила на словосполучення "грьобаний стид", що видалося мені фразеологізмом. Цікавить значення його. Інформації не знайшла.

Comment: Суржик чи з московськојі [_грёбаный_](//russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12623/), а саме евфемізм до [_ёбаный стыд_](http://lurkmore.to/Ёбаный_стыд) (_ув._ московськоју і вельми ненормативне). Всьуди мова про московську чи суржик — тобто неправильнојі украјиньськојі, тому не дуже вважају, шчо це јакось стосује сьа цього роздьілу осьідку.

Comment: @follower, щодо походження — згоден.

Comment: Згідна, але все ж у статтях таке словосполучення використовується, однак, на жаль, російською не шукала. Після вказівки на походження ненормативне аж навіть дещо соромно стало, що таке запитую, не очікувала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Як зазначено в коментарях вище, вислів "грьобаний стид" походить від російського фразеологізму "[ёбанный стыд](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B4)", що означає щось надзвичайно ганебне, [позорище](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozoryshhe). Слово "ёбанный" було замінено на "грьобаний" для того, щоб даний фразеологізм звучав менш вульгарно.

Самого ж слова "грьобаний" я в СУМі не знайшов, однак знайшов його [тут](http://myslovo.com/?dictionary=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (те саме, що довбаний, сучий, дідьків), а також у [статі](http://enpuir.npu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/11811/1/Shumeikina.pdf), де його віднесли до молодіжного сленгу (ст. 96). Проте є в СУМі слово "[стид](http://sum.in.ua/s/styd)".